# SQL Intersection and Union

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `words`, consisting of three columns `word(VARCHAR(16)), doc_id(INT), weight(DOUBLE)`.

Here is what I need to do, I have two queries:

```
SELECT doc_id, weight FROM words WHERE word = 'bla';

doc_id    weight
------    ------
1         0.14
2         0.61
3         0.32
```

and

```
SELECT doc_id, weight FROM words WHERE word = 'blabla';

doc_id    weight
------    ------
2         0.19
3         0.45
4         0.14
```

I need to get the intersection of the two on `doc_id` and select the lower `weight` value as the weight, i.e. I want the results to be:

```
doc_id    weight
------    ------
2         0.19
3         0.32
```

Is there a way to do that in a single query? Doing it in the program makes it damn slow!

I also need to get their `UNION` and select the higher `weight` value, i.e. I want the results to be:

```
doc_id    weight
------    ------
1         0.14
2         0.61
3         0.45
4         0.14
```

Keep in mind that the column `word` and `doc_id` are not unique, so one word can be assigned to many docs.

Comment: Can you provide some example data and show what your desired output is?

Comment: lets say the first query returns {1:0.14 , 2:0.61 , 3:0.32} and the second query returns : {2:0.19 , 3:0.45 , 4:0.14} their intersection should be : {2:0.45 , 3:0.32} and their UNION should be {1:0.14 , 2:0.61 , 3:0.45 , 4:0.14}.  ps: format : {doc_id:weight}

Comment: surely you meant {2:0.19 , 3:0.32} for the intersection?

Comment: @Tohid I edited the question to show this sample data inline with formatting

Comment: @wweicker Thanks :) I didn't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the intersect part it sounds like you want "the lowest weight for all doc_id where the doc_id has one row for the word 'bla' AND one row for the word 'blabla'". That can be found by

```
(untested)
select w1.doc_id, least(min(w1.weight), min(w2.weight)) as minweight 
  from words w1, words w2
 where w1.doc_id = w2.doc_id
   and w1.word = 'bla'
   and w2.word = 'blabla'
 group by w1.doc_id;
```

For the union part what you want is "the highest weight for all doc_id where the doc_id has one row for the word 'bla' OR one row for the word 'blabla'". That can be found by

```
(untested)
select doc_id, max(weight) as maxWeight
  from words
 where word in ('bla', 'blabla')
 group by doc_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select w1.doc_id
     , least(w1.weight, w2.weight) weight
  from words w1
 inner 
  join words w2
    on w1.doc_id = w2.doc_id
 where w1.word = 'bla1'
   and w2.word = 'bla2'



select doc_id
     , max(weight) weight
  from words
 where word in ('blah1', 'blah2')
 group
    by doc_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want this:

```
SELECT doc_id, MIN(weight) MinWeight, MAX(weight) MaxWeight
FROM words
WHERE word IN ('bla','blabla')
GROUP BY doc_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Intersection:

```
SELECT doc_id, MIN(weight) as MinWeight FROM words
WHERE doc_id IN
    (SELECT doc_id FROM words WHERE word = 'bla')
AND doc_id IN
    (SELECT doc_id FROM words WHERE word = 'blabla')
GROUP BY doc_id
```

Union:

```
SELECT doc_id, MAX(weight) as MaxWeight FROM words
WHERE word IN ('bla', 'blabla')
GROUP BY doc_id
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding the below query should work for your req.

-- Lower Weight Query
SELECT Z.doc_id,MIN(weight) as LOWER_WEIGHT
FROM
(
SELECT doc_id, weight FROM words WHERE word = 'bla'
INTERSECT
SELECT doc_id, weight FROM words WHERE word = 'blabla'
)Z
GROUP BY Z.DOC_ID;

-- Higher Weight Query

SELECT Z.doc_id,MAX(weight) as HIGHER_WEIGHT
FROM
(
SELECT doc_id, weight FROM words WHERE word = 'bla'
UNION
SELECT doc_id, weight FROM words WHERE word = 'blabla'
)Z
GROUP BY Z.DOC_ID;

Regards,
Venk